# New alternator new battery

Tags: battery, toyota, starting, alternator, corolla

So my Toyota Corolla 2005 alternator went bad so we purchased a new one off Rockauto.com first time for me personally anyway so after replacing it and reconnecting everything I plug my Battery which is only give or take 3-5months old from Costco and no power whatsoever, so I disconnected the components from the alternator and plugged my battery back in and boom have power so then I replugged the alternator and again no power also when my buddy tried to jump the car thinking the battery needed a bump the jumper cables began to smoke which I’ve never seen or had this issue in the 13-15years I’ve been working with cars/trucks/rigs so can someone please tell me what’s wrong I was told there could be something grounding out but I cannot find it and something could be connected incorrectly but there’s only 2 plugs for the alternator so kinda hard to screw that up so yea super confused

Comment: With the alternator disconnected, your engine starts and runs fine from your battery?

Comment: For a moment obviously cause the alternator isn’t connected so isn’t recharging it but yea it turns over and then cuts off also just found a blown 100amp fuse that’s said to be for the alternator and just put that in and plugged everything in and it blew as soon as I put the power cord to the battery honestly feel the alternators plug has different placements to the ground switch and power points which is causing the faulty connection and acting weird you know? You think?

Comment: Thinkin tomorrow ima get a alternator from Orielys tomorrow and see if I can actually get somewhere since I got the one I have from Rockauto which was a first time experience for me I usually go to a auto parts store local and have no problems and my inlaw was like nah it’s 150.00 cheaper let’s order it instead so I’m thinking the website gave us a different set up than what mine was cause I cannot find any other reason to why this is happening

Comment: Are you certain that you have the battery connected the correct way?  Or did you once connect the battery or jump leads incorrectly.

Comment: Can you post an image of the top of your battery with the cables attached?